# Can you track how long controller was running? jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I'm doing some testing with while controller. 
In my test it checks every 3 seconds for a correct response text and if condition is not met, it repeats. 
I would like to track how long that while controller was running, repeating itself until the condition was correct. 
Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do it via [JMeter Functions](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html), to wit:

- [__time()](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__time) - to get the current timestamp before entering the While Controller
- [__longSum()](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__longSum) - to calculate the delta between 2 timestamps

Something like:

1. Before the While Controller starts put the following expression somewhere in your script:

   ```
   ${__time(,before)}
   ```

   It will store the current timestamp into `${before}` JMeter Variable
2. After the While Controller ends put the following expression somewhere in your script:

   ```
   ${__longSum(${__time(,)},-${before},)}
   ```

   It will get the new current timestamp and calculate the delta by substracting `${before}` variable value from it

Demo:

[image: JMeter Timestamp Delta]

See [How to Use JMeter Functions](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-functions-part-iii) posts series for more information on using JMeter Functions.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [Counter](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Counter) and [Bean Shell Post Processor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_PostProcessor).

Keep Counter Config Element inside the While Controller. The value of Count will be incremented in each iteration.

So, in if condition, you can add BeanShell Post Processor to the sampler inside If controller, and calculate the total time taked using the following formula:

```
count value * 3 = total seconds waited to reach If Condition.
```

Following is the placement of elements in the TestPlan:

```
While Controller
...Counter
...If Controller
......HTTP Sampler
.........Bean Shell Post Processor
```

Image reference:
[image]

Counter Configuration screenshot:
[image]

Bean Shell Post Processor code:

```
int count = Integer.parseInt(vars.get("count"));
int totalTime = count*3;
log.info("total time waited : " + totalTime);
vars.put("totalTime", totalTime);
```

Screenshot:
[image]

Note: the value is saved in `totalTime` variable, so you can refer the value in subsequent requests using `${totalTime}`